# Chaning all links on the page and make them post requests

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a j-script that can replace all links on the page and turn them to forms, so the requests can be sent in post method instead of get method.

my code is:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var linkss=document.links;
    for (var x=0; x<linkss.length; x++) {

        var href=linkss[x].href;
        var u_id="3";

        linkss[x].href="#";
        linkss[x].onclick=function(){
            var myForm = document.createElement("form");
            myForm.action="http://kodaa.ir/s/";
            myForm.target="myFrame";
            myForm.method="POST";

            var url=document.createElement("input");
            url.name="url";
            url.value="www.google.com";
            myForm.appendChild(url);

            var u=document.createElement("input");
            u.name="u_id";
            u.value="3";
            myForm.appendChild(u);

            myForm.submit();
            return false;
        };
    }
}, 2500);
```

So I have two questions:

1- Why isn't my code working? (It just removes the href attribute from  but on click doesn't do anything)

2- How can I pass those two variables(var href AND var u_id) to inside the function?

Thank you for your helps

Comment: Is `u_id` is dynamic based on links ?

Comment: @SKJajoriya Yes, I'll write the code for that later.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML ?

Comment: @SKJajoriya I want this script to be used on different websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following code. You missed to append the form object to the body element. I just added "document.body.appendChild(myForm);" this line.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var linkss=document.links;
    for (var x=0; x<linkss.length; x++) {

        var href=linkss[x].href;
        var u_id="3";

        linkss[x].href="#";
        linkss[x].onclick=function(){
            var myForm = document.createElement("form");
            myForm.action="http://kodaa.ir/s/";
            myForm.target="myFrame";
            myForm.method="POST";

            var url=document.createElement("input");
            url.name="url";
            url.value="www.google.com";
            myForm.appendChild(url);

            var u=document.createElement("input");
            u.name="u_id";
            u.value="3";
            myForm.appendChild(u);
            document.body.appendChild(myForm);

            myForm.submit();
            return false;
        };
    }
}, 2500);
```

Comment: Good, Thanks, What about the second question? How do I pass those variables (href and u_id) inside the function?